# How do I set Data Source password from environment variable in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, token, jetbrains-ide, sqldatasource, datagrip

To connect to DB I have to make an API call to generate a token. Lets say I store this in environment variable `$TOKEN`.

Now while setting up my data source in DataGrip, how can I tell DataGrip to read `$TOKEN` environment variable as its value will keep on changing? Because before opening DataGrip I will make the API call to generate the token and set in a environment variable via script.

Is it possible to read environment variable as a password in DataGrip?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature out of the box.

You can create your custom plugin to provide this kind of authorisation. That is the matter of implementing of on class - `com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseAuthProvider`

See [this plugin](https://github.com/davidsteinsland/postgres-vault-auth/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/com/github/davidsteinsland/postgresvault/VaultAuth.kt) as an example.